# Al importar un archivo de javascript no se ejecuta su contenido

Tags: javascript, html

El problema consiste en que al importar una función de un archivo no sale ningún error pero no ejecuta el código del archivo pruebas.js.

Código pruebas.js

```
import borrar from borrar.js

const boton = document.createElement('button')
boton.type = 'button'
boton.innerText = 'Borrar elemento'

boton.onclick = function() {
    borrar()
}

document.body.appendChild(boton)
```

Codigo borrar.js

```
function borrar() {
    return
}
```

Codigo archivo.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Configurar elementos</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script type="module/javascript" src="pruebas.js"></script>
        <script type="module/javascript" src="borrar.js"></script>

        <button id="crear_elementos">Crear elementos</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tenes varios errores.

- Uso de `type="module/javascript"`:
  El navegador desconoce dicho tipo, por lo que directamente ni descarga los archivos.

  La forma correcta sería utilizar `type="module"`.
- No es necesario incluir el `script borrar.js` en el HTML
- Utilizar `import`:

  Una de las sintaxis para utilizar `import` es:

  ```
  import borrar from './borrar.js'
  ```

  Y para poder utilizar `import` como lo indico, el método que va a ser importado debe ser `export default`:

  ```
  export default function borrar() {...}
  ```

#### Solución:

Para que funcione, tu código final podría ser el siguiente:

**archivo.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Configurar elementos</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="crear_elementos">Crear elementos</button>

  <script type="module" src="pruebas.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**prueba.js**

```js
import borrar from './borrar.js'

const boton = document.createElement('button')
boton.type = 'button'
boton.innerText = 'Borrar elemento'

boton.onclick = function () {
  borrar()
}

document.body.appendChild(boton)
```

**borrar.js**

```js
export default function borrar() {
    return '';
}
```

---

Referencias:

- [Sentencias > import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Comment: me salta el siguiente error Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.  ''                            y cuando cambio module por "text/plain" sigue sin funciunar

Comment: la solución esta en convertir los archivos js a mjs