# ¿Cómo incluyo un archivo JavaScript en otro archivo JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo incluir un archivo JavaScript dentro de otro archivo JavaScript, similar a @import en CSS?

Comment: También se llama `import`. https://es.javascript.info/import-export

Comment: [Esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/575422/16597) puede ser lo que estas buscando.

Answer (score 0):

Para el lado del frontend se utiliza la propiedad type="module" en la etiqueta script del archivo html5 y luego puedes crear tantos archivos .js como quieras.

ejemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="tuScript.js" type="module"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Si bien está relacionado, tu respuesta no es lo que se está preguntando. Tu tienes un archivo HTML, NO un archivo javascript

Answer (score 0):

Depende del contexto.

En HTML se hace así:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="archivo.js"></script>
        <script src="archivo_2.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

En caso que hables de un contexto como Nodejs, dependería según tu necesidad.

En estos casos tenemos a `import` y `export` que sería la sintaxis más moderna.

Ejemplo de uso:

```
// archivo.js
export const mensaje = "Hola desde archivo.js";

// archivo_2.js
import { mensaje } from "./archivo.js";
console.log(mensaje);  // Imprimirá: Hola desde archivo.js
```

La sintaxis más antigua sería `const archivo = requiere("archivo.js");` y para la exportación sería `module.exports`

Un ejemplo:

```
// archivo.js
module.exports = { mensaje: "Hola desde archivo.js" };

// archivo_2.js
const { mensaje } = require("./archivo.js");
console.log(mensaje);  // Imprimirá: Hola desde archivo.js
```

CommonJS (`require`/`module.exports`):
Sintaxis:

Importación: Se utiliza `require` para importar módulos.

Exportación: Se utiliza `module.exports` para exportar valores desde un módulo.

Evaluación Dinámica: Las importaciones y exportaciones son evaluadas dinámicamente durante el tiempo de ejecución.

Contexto de Uso:

Node.js: CommonJS es comúnmente utilizado en Node.js.
Ambientes no compatibles con ESM: En entornos que no admiten ECMAScript Modules (ESM), como Node.js antes del soporte total de ESM.

ECMAScript Modules (`import`/`export`):
Sintaxis:

Importación: Se utiliza `import` para importar módulos.

Exportación: Se utiliza `export` para exportar valores desde un módulo.

Evaluación Estática: Las importaciones y exportaciones son evaluadas estáticamente durante el tiempo de análisis (fase de carga).

Contexto de Uso:

Navegadores Modernos: ESM se utiliza en entornos de navegadores modernos y en algunos entornos de desarrollo de JavaScript.

Node.js (con soporte ESM): En versiones recientes de Node.js, se ha añadido soporte para ECMAScript Modules.

Espero haber resuelto tu duda.